# Scrape product Image url from a website where content is uploading dynamiclly

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I am not able to scrape the product images. I am using ajax. My ajax file is  test.html  and here is my code :-

```
$( "#click_me" ).click(function () {
     $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        asyn:false, 
        success: function(result){
         console.log(result);
    }});
});
```

Test.php file code :-

```
$url="http://www.kohls.com/catalog/bedroom-mattresses-accessories-furniture.jsp?CN=Room:Bedroom+Category:Mattresses%20%26%20Accessories+Department:Furniture&cc=bed_bath-TN3.0-S-mattresses";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 ");
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$out = str_replace("\n", '', $out);
echo $out;
```

Note: please check the `$url`. The images are populating dynamically and we are not able to scrape them . Please I need quick guidance , I have used pythonjs as well to scrape them but that didn't work !!!
    Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse out the images from the HTML. DOMDocument is a good choice for this.

example code (UNTESTED but should work in theory)

```
$url="http://www.kohls.com/catalog/bedroom-mattresses-accessories-furniture.jsp?CN=Room:Bedroom+Category:Mattresses%20%26%20Accessories+Department:Furniture&cc=bed_bath-TN3.0-S-mattresses";

$html=file_get_contents($url);
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("img") as $img){
$src=$img->getAttribute("src");
if(empty($src)){continue;}
$src='http://www.kohls.com'.$src;
$filename=basename($src);
echo "downloading ".$filename.PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents($src));
}
```

just replace file_get_contents with your curl functions if you want curl
(also this is rather memory hungry, as the entire image will be downloaded to ram no matter how big it is. with curl, you could optimize it with CURLOPT_FILE to write to a file directly. could save a lot of RAM if you want to download images from NASA or the like)

Comment: No the thing is $html=file_get_contents($url); will not fetch the html of products images . Because "products images " are uploading using Ajax call and when i send request to scrape the url , it never scrapes products html .So according to your logic i will just stuck into a loop only , i may never get image's src .